# unable to import a file to a to a python script and to log the print statement to another file using command line argument

Tags: python, django

i want to import a .py file lets say param.py (which has some variable),through command line argument, also i want to redirect print statement of a main file let say test.py to a file.Also i want to use param.py variables to test.py script.Can anyone help me with this?here is my code.

**For param.py**

`target_mac = "000000000000FFFF"
 ACEM1_slave="20"
 ACEM2_slave="11"
 DCEM_slave="50"`

**For test.py**

```
`//Please add the code, as per my requirement.`
```

I want to pass the argument in command line as: **py test.py -f param.py -o out.txt**

where, test.py is the main file,param.py is the config file. & out.txt is the log file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something such as this, which uses `argparse` to parse the arguments, and `runpy.run_path()` to load the variables from the config file.

**test.py**

```
import argparse
import functools
import runpy

# Parse the script arguments
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-f')
parser.add_argument('-o')
args = parser.parse_args()

# Load the config file
config = runpy.run_path(args.f)

# Open the output file for writing
output = open(args.o, 'a')
print >>output, 'This will go to the output file'
print >>output, config['target_mac']
print >>output, config['ACEM1_slave']
print >>output, config['ACEM2_slave']
print >>output, config['DCEM_slave']

# Flush and close the output file
output.flush()
output.close()
```

The variables would be available via the `config` dictionary and the `print` statements are redirected to the output file. It can be run as intended:

```
python test.py -f param.py -o out.txt
```

After running it, `out.txt` contains:

```
This will go to the output file
000000000000FFFF
20
11
50
```

You could even make the variables in `param.py` available as variables in the global scope for `test.py`.

```
# Load the config file
config = runpy.run_path(args.f)

# Update the global variables with the config
globals().update(config)
```

Then you could work with the variables directly in `test.py`:

```
print(target_mac)
```

Comment: @ Will Thanks, it worked. only problem is i am getting error message in print statement i.e. print = functools.partial(print, file=output)  .When i commented this statement i am getting the output in console. Now, i got the idea i will do that log capture stuff. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @Ayush - what version of Python are you using? The code for `print` above will work with Python 3, but won't work with Python 2. If you're using Python 2 there is an alternative way to use `print`.

Comment: @Ayush - I've updated the answer with the syntax required for Python 2. The `print` statements use the `>>output` syntax to redirect to the output file.